# Keyboard and mouse not working on brand new formatted disk install of Ubuntu 20.04.3 with Kernel 5.11.xx-generic

Tags: kernel, keyboard, mouse, input

I've been having a bug for the past few months where any kernel newer than 5.10.-43-generic (I can't remember the exact kernel version. I tried looking it up, but I only remember it being before 5.11 and ending with a -43) would cause my keyboard and mouse to no longer work on login.

I decided to reinstall Ubuntu after having zero luck figuring out the problem. Only that one old kernel was working for me, and I've tried every other kernel that my system has update into grub. I wiped my disk completely and did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.3 with Kernel 5.11-28-generic (again, I can't remember the exact kernel version.)

I'm dumbfounded that a complete wipe of my ubuntu disk and all of it's partitions with a fresh clean install is resulting in this exact same issue. I figured maybe I had broken a package somewhere (which I previously tried to repair in recovery with dpkg to no avail.) The keyboard and mouse work fine while using the live media disk... But now that I'm on the disk encryption screen I'm having the same problem as before.

I'm going to reinstall again using Ubuntu 21.10 and see if there's a difference.

Any help would be appreciated. And if I can get this fixed I'll update this post to reflect that.

Thanks.

Comment: You're a little vague with details (no clues as to which Ubuntu 20.04 product you're using), but given you mention you're having trouble with kernels higher than 5.10; why not use media that installed the GA kernel stack (ie. 5.4) and just remain on that *stable* stack?  Even media that installs using the 5.8 kernel should work by your reasoning; though you'll have to switch to GA kernel stack before upgrade (as 5.8 will upgrade to 5.13).  Some 20.04 media allows you to select kernel stack during install (`subiquity` installs), others its the ISO itself that dictates the chosen kernel stack

Comment: Ubuntu Server ISOs let you select stack on install; Ubuntu Desktop ISOs default to HWE so you'd need to use 20.04, 20.04.1, or 20.04.2 then switch to GA post-install to remain on GA, Ubuntu *flavors* default to GA for 20.04 & 20.04.1 but default to HWE on 20.04.2 or higher media (ISOs using `ubiquity` can also recognize hardware and switch you to OEM stack).  ie. You can select or *somewhat control* stack in use by ISO used to install; you didn't say if you're asking about server/desktop/flavor etc, nor give ISO specifics...